# {{parent.child.0.field}} it not resolved, if child is java.util.Set. Works if it was a java.util.List

Tags: java, mustache

**Template:**

```
{{parent.child.0.field}}
```

**Context:**

```
Mustache.Compiler c = Mustache.compiler();
Parent parentObj = new Parent();
Map<String, Object> ctx = Maps.newHashMap();
ctx.put("parent", parentObj);
c.compile(templateHtml).execute(ctx);
```

**Exception:**

```
"exception" : "com.samskivert.mustache.MustacheException$Context",
  "message" : "Missing context for compound variable 'parent.child.0.field' on line 1. '0' was not found."
```

Any workaround without changing the template or datatype of Child from Set to List ?

Comment: I typhoons you can iterate over sets, but not access them with index. Which element would you expect to get from your set using "index" 0?

Comment: ugh! my bad :) blindly expecting js and java to work the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) dosn't have [get(int index)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)) method like List.

Comment: in other works, my question is how do I render the values inside a set in the template ?

Comment: @AnandRockzz convert the Set to a List

Comment: @YCF_L ended up with replacing the template like this: `template = template.replace("{{parent.child.","{{parent.childAsList.")` and introduced a method in Parent class like this: `public List<Child> getChildAsList() { return Lists.newArrayList(this.child);}`